# With shields.io, how to set specific version of badge?

Tags: github, npm, shields.io

I want to know how to set specific version in shields.io.

I'm working on README.MD in GitHub, and making my own README.md template. I want to set specific version of next-js badge, for example like below:

[image: npm]

But now I only have latest version. In shields.io, is there an option for scoping or tag? I could not find how to set version. What is the valid text for the scope of below picture? For example, I want to set 8.x.x version not 9.x.x.

[image]

Comment: That badge is for showing the current NPM release version of your *own* package (e.g. see https://github.com/textbook/fauxauth), not for showing your dependency on other packages.

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for poor question but good answer,because I’m new to code and not a English native, I think I can not fully understand but your answers are very helpful to me, again thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the NPM (scoped) badge will inject the latest version of your npm package automatically from the NPM servers/registeries. So you just have to fill necessary data, which is [scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/scope.html) name *(if you are using one)* and the package name; it will convert to something like this `@somescope/some package name`, and it will search through the NPM for the latest public version of it.

But if you intend to create badges for your project dependencies *(Shiels.io will make a peer connection for checking them and will update them whenever they get updated)*, you have to use the [Platform & Version Support dependencies](https://shields.io/category/platform-support), which will give you the ability to inject live versions of your dependencies from the GitHub repo. So, for instance, if your `package.json` exists in your master repo, you can use *GitHub `package.json` dependency version (prod)*; then you just need to fill your GitHub username, your desired repo, and package name in your `package.json`.

So let's say I want to get my `react` version from *React-Telegram-DK-Test* repo that exist under my username. I can simply do it like below:

[image]

If, in any case, your project was in the private repo or not in GitHub at all, you just have to create your badge manually and update it whenever the dependency version gets updated. It is available in the *Your badge* section.

So you can make a static version like this:

[image]

The result will be available under [generated URL](https://img.shields.io/badge/Next-V9.4.4-blue) like this:

[image: badge]

Comment: I have a question, If I need to use Platform & Version Support dependencies, then how can I point the location of package.json?
for example, my repo have two directories(frontend and backend) and each directory has package.json. thanks

Comment: @stefancho Well, in this particular case you should use *GitHub package.json dependency version (subfolder of monorepo)*. It is exactly the same as the last one but in *filename* section you can specify the directory of your `package.json`.

Comment: thank you it perfectly work! ,but after updating package.json, it takes 3~4 minutes to get data from server, after few minutes it shows me specific dependency from sub folder